# (Matlab) Want to create a MATLAB program that does not require Matlab to run it

Tags: matlab

Let say I wrote a program which has GUI. And I want to share with my friend who don't have MATLAB in his computer. Can I some how convert it to Java or other language? I tried using `deploytool` but it need the target computer install MCR in order to work.

Comment: No, you cannot convert it to any other language. Yes, if compiled, you have to install the MCR.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you  should use [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/) (which `deploytool` is part of) to create a standalone executable from your GUI. The end-user does require the MCR (MATLAB Component Runtime) to run your compiled application, but you can freely distribute it if you have a license of MATLAB Compiler.

Note: last I looked, the application are OS-specific, i.e. if you use Windows to compile your application, you can only deploy in on a Windows platform.